# How to configure Emacs to archive Done tasks to archive file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I keep all tasks in a `todo.org` file. After a task is done, I'd like to select and archive it to a separate `archive.org` file. I want to set this up in my config file, of course, not as a per-file header.

I tried this:

```
(setq org-archive-location (concat org-directory "~/Dropbox/logs/archive.org::"))
```

Which *seems* to work; I see a message that the task has been archived to my chosen path. But--when I open `archive.org`, nothing is there. Ever. Then, whenever I close and reopen Emacs, I see the error message `Symbol's value as variable is void: org-directory`.

So: **How do I properly configure Emacs to archive tasks I choose to the correct place?** Still an Org mode neophyte, so have mercy.

EDIT: Using Emacs 25.3.2, and Org 9.1.7.

Comment: Whenever you see something is `void`, find out where it is defined and try loading that library.  In this case, you can place `(require 'org)` in your `.emacs` / `init.el` before any `org-mode` customizations such as the one listed in your question above.  See also things like `eval-after-load` ... and everyone seems to enjoy using `use-package` to delay loading libraries until actually needed ...

Comment: Let us assume that the default value of `org-directory` is `"~/org"`.  Now, if we concatenate `"~/org"` with `"~/Dropbox/logs/archive.org::"`, we get something very strange indeed:  `"~/org~/Dropbox/logs/archive.org::"`.  Thus, you probably want to eliminate `(concat org-directory` and the extra closing `)`.  If you want to see the value of a variable, type `C-h v` aka `M-x describe-variable` and you can see how it was configured -- in this case, incorrectly.

Comment: @lawlist Not sure I understand. I haven't set a default value for org-directory (should I?), and all I have now is a `todo.org` file in `~/Dropbox/logs/`. What's the specific syntax I need here to get tasks properly archived to `~/Dropbox/logs/archive.org`?

Comment: If you open up a brand spanking new Emacs 26 without any user configuration, and type `M-x describe-variable RET org-directory RET`, you get a `*Help*` window that says the value is `~/org`.  In older versions of Emacs, it may be necessary to first type:  `M-x eval-expression RET (require 'org) RET` to load the library before you can see the value of a variable defined inside that library.  `concat` means put strings together:  `(concat "hello" "-" "world)` will give you `"hello-world"`.  In your case, you don't want `"~/org~/Dropbox/logs/archive.org::"` because that directory doesn't exist.

Comment: You *probably want*:  `(setq org-archive-location "~/Dropbox/logs/archive.org::")`

Comment: @lawlist That worked--but now I see another part of my problem: Emacs opens `archive.org` in a buffer and puts the done task there, but doesn't write to the file until I save the buffer or close (with save) Emacs. That seems sub-optimal, but now I at least have archiving. Thank you.

Comment: Here is an idea you might wish to try experimenting with to save the org-archive buffer.  I haven't tested it yet .... https://gist.github.com/lawlist/303d3000eeb25d4885963ba5514e57d9

Comment: I fixed a few typos in the function -- it should work now.

Comment: Thanks @lawlist. Mind upvoting this one, for future visibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inasmuch as the O.P. has also expressed (in a comment underneath the original question) a desire to automatically save the target archive buffer, this answer addresses that as well:

```lisp
(require 'org)

(setq org-archive-location "~/Dropbox/logs/archive.org::")

(defun org-archive-save-buffer ()
  (let ((afile (org-extract-archive-file (org-get-local-archive-location))))
    (if (file-exists-p afile)
      (let ((buffer (find-file-noselect afile)))
        (if (y-or-n-p (format "Save (%s)" buffer))
          (with-current-buffer buffer
            (save-buffer))
          (message "You expressly chose _not_ to save (%s)" buffer)))
      (message "Ooops ... (%s) does not exist." afile))))

(add-hook 'org-archive-hook 'org-archive-save-buffer)
```